# Wordpress Date, Month Translation

Tags: wordpress

I have the wordpress language set to romanian and when I select the date format to j F (date and month) in general settings, I get the month in english e.g. 5 June, instead of romanian, 5 Iunie.

I've used this `return date(get_option('date_format'));` or this `return date(get_option('j F'));` but the month is still in english.

I've tried some suggestions from other similar questions but for the life of me, I can't seem to make it work. Any suggestions I can try?

Comment: Can You tell me what value selected in admin for this section "Settings > General" ?

Comment: @Jinesh I've tried the default j F Y , and custom j F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date()` function is not specific to WordPress - it is part of the core of PHP and by default, uses English for all abbreviations or full date parts. See the [php.net doc page for details](https://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Formatting a date is very different from translating/localizing it.

Outside of WordPress, or if you just want to do things manually, you can use either [`setlocale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) in combination with [`strftime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), or [`IntlDateFormatter`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php). For example, for Romanian:

```php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ro_RO','Romanian');
echo strftime("%e %B");
// "5 iunie"
```

---

However, the above can be complicated, so an easier way is to user WordPress's built in function for translating dates into different locales: [`date_i18n()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n). It uses the locale you set in your Wordpress settings, which makes things very easy. If you just want to echo the date in your language & with your setting for formatting, this alone should work:

```php
echo date_i18n(get_option('date_format'));
```